# Visitor tracking scopes in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying figure out what scope to use when tracking the users, the dimension are listed below in both UA/GA4 and why these scopes are chosen? It is for a web-page.

[image: UA]
[image: GA4]

Answer (score 2):

User scope is typically used when the value is user-specific and is unlikely to change, or if it changes, then we only ever want to see the latest value.

Scope determines the atomicity of a dimension. For a hit scope: there can be only one value for this dimension for every hit. For a session: only one value per session. For a user: only one value per user.

Here's more on dimensions and scopes: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Once you know what are scopes and how they work, you should be able to know when which scope is applicable. When not sure, just use hit scope.